# Al actualizar de Symfony 5.4.7 a 5.4.8 la autenticación no funciona, pero tampoco muestra error

Tags: symfony

He actualizado desde **Symfony 5.4.7** a **Symfony 5.4.8**, y al intentar autenticar vuelve a redireccionar al login pero no me muestra ningún error. La autenticación es a través de un Formulario de Login contra base de datos; expongo la configuración que tengo hasta el momento:

```
#security.yaml:
security:
    enable_authenticator_manager: true
    password_hashers:
        legacy:
            algorithm: sha512
            cost: 10
        App\Entity\Usuario:
            algorithm: 'auto'
            cost: 10
            migrate_from:
                - legacy

    providers:
        userdb_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\Usuario
                property: username
                manager_name: default
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        app:
            pattern: ^/*
            provider: userdb_provider
            form_login:
                login_path: usuario_login
                use_forward: true
                check_path: usuario_loginCheck
                failure_forward: false
                require_previous_session: false
                enable_csrf: true
                always_use_default_target_path: true
            logout:
                path: usuario_logout
                target: app_homepage
                csrf_parameter: _csrf_token                   # Optional (defaults to "_csrf_token")                
            
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
        - { path: ^/configurar, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
        - { path: ^/configurar/*, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
        - { path: ^/*, roles: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY, ROLE_CONS_NAC, ROLE_ESP_NAC, ROLE_ESP_PROV, ROLE_ESP_MUN, ROLE_ESP_AS, ROLE_EST_AS, ROLE_EST_MUN, ROLE_EST_GBT, ROLE_J_GBT, ROLE_EST_HOSP, ROLE_EST_HOMA, ROLE_MEDICO, ROLE_GENETISTA], requires_channel: https }
    role_hierarchy:
       ROLE_CONS_NAC:   ROLE_CONS_NAC       
       ROLE_ESP_AS:     ROLE_ESP_AS
       ROLE_EST_AS:     ROLE_EST_MUN
       ROLE_ESP_NAC:    ROLE_ESP_NAC
       ROLE_ESP_PROV:   ROLE_ESP_PROV
       ROLE_ESP_MUN:    ROLE_ESP_MUN
       ROLE_EST_MUN:    ROLE_EST_MUN
       ROLE_J_GBT:      ROLE_J_GBT
       ROLE_EST_GBT:    ROLE_EST_GBT
       ROLE_EST_HOSP:   ROLE_EST_HOSP
       ROLE_EST_HOMA:   ROLE_EST_HOMA
       ROLE_GENETISTA:  ROLE_GENETISTA
       ROLE_MEDICO:     ROLE_MEDICO
```

La entidad Usuario (resumida):

```
namespace App\Entity;


use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\EquatableInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * Usuario
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="usuario")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UsuarioRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity("username", message="Ya existe un usuario con ese identificador")
 */
class Usuario implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface, EquatableInterface, \Serializable
{

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     * @ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="usuario_id_id_seq", initialValue=1, allocationSize=100)   
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * 
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="El identificador es obligatorio.")
     * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", unique=true, length=100, nullable=false)
     */
    private $username;

  
    /**
     * @var string
     * 
     * @Assert\Length(
     *      min=6, 
     *      max=255,
     *      minMessage="La contraseña debe tener como mínimo {{ limit }} caracteres",
     *      maxMessage="La contraseña no puede exceder los {{ limit }} caracteres."
     * )
     * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="activo", type="boolean", nullable=false)
     */
    private $activo;


    /**
     * @var type \App\Entity\Rol
     * 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Rol", fetch="EAGER")     
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="rol_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false, onDelete="RESTRICT")
     */
    private $rol;
   
        
    /**
     * Set username
     *
     * @param string $username
     * @return Usuario
     */
    public function setUsername(?string $username): self
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get username
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getUsername(): string
    {
        return $this->username;
    }
    
    /**
     * 
     * @return array
     */
    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        $coleccion = new ArrayCollection();
        $coleccion->add($this->getRol()->getToken());
        $coleccion[] = "ROLE_USER";

        return array_unique($coleccion->toArray());
    }

    /**
     * Set password
     *
     * @param string $password
     * @return Usuario
     */
    public function setPassword(?string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get password
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPassword(): string
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Set activo
     *
     * @param bool $activo
     * @return Usuario
     */
    public function setActivo(bool $activo): self
    {
        $this->activo = $activo;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get activo
     *
     * @return bool 
     */
    public function getActivo(): bool
    {
        return $this->activo;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }


    /**
     * Add rol
     *
     * @param Rol $rol
     * @return Usuario
     */
    public function setRol(Rol $rol): self
    {
        $this->rol = $rol;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return Rol|null
     */
    public function getRol(): ?Rol
    {
        return $this->rol;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return void
     */
    public function eraseCredentials(): void
    {
        
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSalt(): string
    {
        return '';
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isAccountNonExpired(): bool
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isAccountNonLocked(): bool
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isCredentialsNonExpired(): bool
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isEnabled(): bool
    {
        return $this->activo;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return string
     */
    public function serialize(): string
    {
        return serialize([
            $this->username,
            $this->nombreCompleto,
            $this->password,
            $this->activo,
            $this->id,
            $this->idPublico
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param type $serialized
     * @return void
     */
    public function unserialize($serialized): void
    {
        list(
                $this->username,
                $this->nombreCompleto,
                $this->password,
                $this->activo,
                $this->id,
                $this->idPublico
                ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return array
     */
    public function __sleep(): array
    {
        return ['username', 'nombreCompleto', 'password', 'activo', 'id', 'idPublico'];
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return string
     */
    public function __toString(): string
    {
        return $this->nombreCompleto;
    }

          
    /**
     * 
     * @param UserInterface $user
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isEqualTo(UserInterface $user): bool
    {
        if ($this->getUsername() === $user->getUsername() && $this->getPassword() === $user->getPassword() && $this->getSalt() === $user->getSalt() && $this->isEnabled() === $user->isEnabled()) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     * * */
    public function getUserIdentifier(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->username;
    }  
    

}
```

La clase UsuarioRepository:

```
namespace App\Repository;

use App\Entity\EstructuraOrganizativa;
use App\Entity\Usuario;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Security\User\UserLoaderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UnsupportedUserException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordUpgraderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * Description of UsuarioRepository
 *
 */
class UsuarioRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository implements UserLoaderInterface, PasswordUpgraderInterface
{

    /**
     * 
     * @param ManagerRegistry $registry
     */
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, Usuario::class);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param string $username
     * @return Usuario|null
     * @throws UsernameNotFoundException
     */
    public function loadUserByIdentifier(string $username): ?Usuario
    {
        $dql = "SELECT u, b r, eo, teo FROM App:Usuario u LEFT JOIN u.buzonInterno b JOIN u.rol r JOIN u.estructuraOrganizativa eo JOIN eo.tipoEstructuraOrganizativa teo WHERE u.username = :username AND r.id IN (SELECT rr.id FROM App:Rol rr WHERE rr.habilitado = true)";
        $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery($dql);
        $query->setParameter('username', $username);
        $query->setMaxResults(1);
        $query->useQueryCache(true);

        return $query->getOneOrNullResult();
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param type $username
     * @return Usuario|null
     * @throws UsernameNotFoundException
     */
    public function loadUserByUsername(string $username): ?Usuario
    {
        return $this->loadUserByIdentifier($username);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param UserInterface $user
     * @return Usuario|null
     * @throws UnsupportedUserException
     */
    public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
    {
        $class = \get_class($user);
        if (!$this->supportsClass($class)) {
            throw new UnsupportedUserException(
                            sprintf(
                                    'Instances of "%s" are not supported.', $class
                            )
            );
        }
        return $this->findOneJoinedEstructuraOrganizativa($user->getId());
    }

    /**
     * Used to upgrade (rehash) the user's password automatically over time.
     * 
     * @param UserInterface $user
     * @param string $newHashedPassword
     * @throws UnsupportedUserException
     */
    public function upgradePassword(UserInterface $user, string $newHashedPassword): void
    {
        if (!$user instanceof Usuario) {
            throw new UnsupportedUserException(sprintf('Instances of "%s" are not supported.', \get_class($user)));
        }

        $user->setPassword($newHashedPassword);
        $this->_em->persist($user);
        $this->_em->flush();
    }
      

}
```

Y por ulitmo el action que maneja el formulario de login:

```
/**
     * 
     * @param AuthenticationUtils $authUtils
     * @param ManagerRegistry $manager
     * @return Response
     */
    public function renderLoginFormAction(AuthenticationUtils $authUtils, ManagerRegistry $manager)
    {
         $error = $authUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
        $ultimoUsuario = $authUtils->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render('Usuario/login.html.twig', [
                    'last_username' => $ultimoUsuario,
                    'error' => $error,
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución encontrada se basa en los cambios que ha surtido el sistema de autenticación de Symfony y su nuevo componente de seguridad. Partiendo de que esta aplicación en específico la he estado actualizando desde Symfony 2.8, la filosofía ha cambiado un poco, y se han agregado algunas clases que permiten desacoplar y "personalizar" más el proceso de autenticación para el caso que se realice desde cero, como lo hice yo, aunque es básicamente hacer un `make:auth`

Primero:
En el fichero `framework.yaml`, establecer:

```
framework:
    session:
        cookie_secure: true
```

Segundo:
En el fichero `security.yaml` se debe establecer para el firewall configurado el `entry_point` que manejará las peticiones que requieren autenticación o "han perdido la autenticación" por sesión expirada o cookie eliminada por ejemplo.

```
security:
    firewalls:
        app:                
            entry_point: App\Security\AuthenticationEntryPoint
            form_login:
                login_path: usuario_login
```

Definición de *App\Security\AuthenticationEntryPoint:*

```
namespace App\Security;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\EntryPoint\AuthenticationEntryPointInterface;

class AuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPointInterface
{

    public const LOGIN_ROUTE = 'usuario_login';

    private $urlGenerator;

    public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator)
    {
        $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
    }

    public function start(Request $request, AuthenticationException $authException = null): Response
    {
        if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            return new Response("Unautorized!!!", 401);
        }

        $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('security', 'Debe autenticarse.');
        return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate(self::LOGIN_ROUTE));
    }

}
```

Esta clase es importante, al actualizar el framework me estaba faltando su definición en la configuración del firewall. Básicamente en la función `start()` comparo si la petición es vía AJAX y se envía una Respuesta con código 401, de manera tal que se pueda tratar del lado del cliente por este código, y si no lo es, hacer una redirección al routing que muestra el formulario de login.

Tercero:
Se realizan algunas correcciones en las reglas de control de acceso del firewall, sustituyendo `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY` por `PUBLIC_ACCESS`, y la primera regla:

```
path: ^/login, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS, requires_channel: https }
```

por

```
 path: ^/acceso, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS, requires_channel: https }
```

teniendo en cuenta que el routing del login genera una url del tipo `/acceso`

Cuarto:
En el controller de Seguridad se define el action `logoutAction`, aunque no creo sea necesario:

```
public function logoutAction(): void
{
    // controller can be blank: it will never be called!
    throw new \Exception('Don\'t forget to activate logout in security.yaml');
}
```

El resto de las definiciones especificadas en la pregunta original se mantienen igual. Espero le sea de ayuda a otros!!!!.